# My PHP generated HTML file is being downloaded twice?

Tags: php, html, download

I have a function that creates an HTML page and forces the download.  Once the function is run, for some reason it is downloaded to the users computers twice.  Here is my code

```
public function actionDownload($params)
    {   
        // Get the article
        $co_model=new Contentorder;
        $co_model->load($params['id']);
        $co=$co_model->getFields();

        $file_name=str_replace(array(' ','.','&',',','\''),'',strtolower($co['article_title'])).".html";

        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
        header('Content-type: text/html');

        echo '<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>'.$co['article_title'].'</title></head><body>';
        if ($co['id_contenttype']==3){  // Reusable
            $lco_model=new Librarycontent;
            $lco_model->load($co['id_librarycontent']);

            $res=$lco_model->getFields();
            if ($res['id_reusabletype']==3) // Youtube
            {   
                echo $res['reusable_file'];
            }   
        }   

        echo $co['article'].'</body></html>';
        exit;
    }
```

It successfully forces the download on the dynamically created HTML file, but it is downloaded twice for some reason when I only want the file to be downloaded once.

EDIT ------ Here are the headers
[image]

Comment: If its downloaded twice, it's certainly asked twice. Checked the network traffic? Are you sure you didn't add two handlers on the same button or something like this ?

Comment: I checked the network traffic and the request is only being send once.  I am making the request by jquery ajax and updating an iframe to force the download.

Comment: So you send the ajax request (which make you download (content-disposition: attachment)) and then update an iframe to download (2nd download ?). Try removing your iframe updating.